GPG errorが解消されない。
以前まで動作していたdocker、centos、laravel（Linuxディストリビューション内）の環境で、docker-compose up -d --buildを行うと、ネットワークにつながらなくなった為、DNSを設定する事で、ネットワークにつながったのですが、今度はGPG errorになりました。
DB用のdockerfileの
FROM mysql:8.0.28

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install locales-all # ここでエラー

エラー内容
docker-compose build --no-cache
WARN[0000] /home/realize_corporation/todokusuri/docker/docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete 
[+] Building 2.2s (6/7)                                                                                                                                                               docker:default
 => [db internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 473B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [db internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.28                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [db internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [db 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.28                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [db internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 66B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [db 2/3] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install locales-all                                                                                                                     2.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                                               
 > [db 2/3] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install locales-all:                                                                                                                                
0.261 Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [34.8 kB]                                                                                                            
0.275 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]                                                                                                                                   
0.278 Get:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease [22.1 kB]                                                                                                                              
0.315 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [56.6 kB]                                                                                                                          
0.339 Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [595 kB]
0.367 Err:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
0.367   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
0.448 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7909 kB]
0.976 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [8788 B]
1.746 Reading package lists...
2.146 W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
2.146 E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install locales-all" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

上記を解消する為、
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
を実行致しましたが、
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.6dmIdc4qcL/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
gpg: key B7B3B788A8D3785C: "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

上記の状態になり、GPGキーが更新されていない？様です。
1日考えましたが、解決せず、こちらご教示頂けないでしょうか？

エラーに出ている通り (MySQL の) GPG キーが古くなっているのが原因です。
MySQL リポジトリのトップを見ると以下のように新しい GPG キーが用意されています。
https://repo.mysql.com/
[FILE] RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql                 04-Nov-2021 10:51     2k
[FILE] RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022            17-Jan-2022 10:22     3k
[FILE] RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023            24-Oct-2023 15:02     3k

方法1: 参照する Docker イメージを更新する
質問で使用している mysql:8.0.28 のイメージは、約2年前の古いバージョンです。
このバージョンでなければならない特別な理由がない限りは、より新しいバージョンを使用してください。
8.0.xx だと "8.0.36" がありますが、バージョンのみ指定すると Oracle Linux ベースのイメージに置き換わっているようなので、Debian を使いたいのであれば Dockerfile を以下のように修正します。
FROM mysql:8.0.36-debian

方法2: Dockerfiile を修正して新しい GPG キーを取り込む
どうしても 8.0.28 を使用しなければならない場合には、前述の通り新しい GPG キーを取り込んでからパッケージの更新を行う必要があります。
参考:
MySQL入門：GPGエラーへの対応

FROM mysql:8.0.28

RUN mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list.disabled

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
       curl \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sSfL https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023 | gpg --import
RUN gpg --batch --export "B7B3B788A8D3785C" > /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg
RUN mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list.disabled /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
RUN apt-get update


